# react-native-bluetooth getting error when "Debug JS remotely"

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager) library to connect my HM-10 BLE by running `react-native run-ios` and I did successfully connect to my device using the [example code](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/blob/master/example/App.js).

However, when I try to open the debug page by selecting `Debug JS remotely` I am getting an error:

> Connection to http://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy?role=client timed
>   out. Are you running node proxy? If you are running on the device,
>   check if you have the right IP address in RCTWebSocketExecutor.m

Does any know why this is happening? Any advise or comments would be really appreciated!

Comment: make sure device and development machine  both are connected to same network!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Turns out this is a network issue. I had to match my wifi the same for both dev machine and device.